# why std::vector allow to use [] to assign, but the size() and capacity() doesn't change?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I make a test as below, create a vector and set it's capacity to 1, then use `v[100]=100;` to directly assign v[100] but doesn't triggle core dump, why？ vector v shouldn't have enough memory to access v[100], but v[100] is successfully to be assigned 100, and the size and capacity() remains to 0 and 1, how to understand this?

```
int main(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(1); 
    v[100]=100;                      //here does't triggle core dump, wired
    std::cout<<v.size()<<std::endl;  //0 
    std::cout<<v.capacity()<<std::endl; //1
    std::cout<<v[100]<<std::endl;    //100
return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's undefined behavior, it's pure luck that it works. The program isn't required to crash if you access invalid memory. To quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at): _"Unlike std::map::operator[], this operator never inserts a new element into the container. Accessing a nonexistent element through this operator is undefined behavior."_

Answer (score 7):

It's because [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) doesn't do bounds checking. If you use an invalid index it leads to undefined behavior.

If you want bounds checking then you should use [`std::vector::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at). It will throw an exception if you use an invalid index.

```
v.at(100)=100; // this will throw a std::out_of_range exception
```